# Three dimension chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data presented like this:

```
| endpoint  | calls |   date  |
| GET-url1  |   200 | 2020-04 |
| GET-url1  |   100 | 2020-05 |
| POST-url1 |   500 | 2020-04 |
| POST-url1 |   700 | 2020-06 |
...
```

This result comes from a Sql query.
What I would like achieve is having a chart like this:
[image]

Where line = endpoint; X = date, Y = calls

Is it possible to have this kind of chart from the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Insert>Pivot Chart, you can configure it like this:

[image]

You put the endpoint in "Legend (series)", the calls in "Values" and the date in "Axis (Categories)". You can right-click the chart and select 'Change Chart Type' to change it from the default bar to a line chart.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working like a charm!